# unable to create a first rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

iam new to rubyonrails, i have installed rubyonrails 3.2.6, i have created a new project by typing **rails new demo** iam getting following error

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL
using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.

please help me in creating my first rails project

Thanks
Saikrishna

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.beginnerruby.com/rails-troubleshooting/fixing-opensslbundler-issue-for-rails-on-debian/) should solve your problem.

**UPDATE**

Add `source :rubygems` at the beginning of your gemfile.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, after reinstalling rvm along with open-ssl ,trying to create rails project getting following

Comment: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension./home/saikrishna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Comment: --with-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/home/saikrishna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
 --with-sqlite3-dir
 --without-sqlite3-dir
 --with-sqlite3-include
 --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
 --with-sqlite3-lib
 --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
 --enable-local
 --disable-local

Comment: Gem files will remain installed in /home/saikrishna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/saikrishna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: no dint install does it come bundeled with rails or need to install

Comment: it does not, it's a db, you got to install it separately.  once done, install the sqlite3 gem.

Comment: hi Thanks for reply, i have installed SQLlite3 gem, trying to migrate db rake db:create iam getting error home/saikrishna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'therubyracer (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: The `source :rubygems` is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be good practice, but I had this same issue.
I solved it by changing the first line in my Gemfile from:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```