# OSX Ruby Error when starting a Rails scaffolding: Could not load OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I had been racking my head on this for far too long.

I am installing ruby via RVM. I had no troubles while installing Ruby. The issue come with using openssl with anything in ruby i have tried the what seems to be the standard solution of installing RVM openssl package and reinstalling Ruby with --with-openssl-dir.

I have tired every combination of gcc-4.2 vs llvm-gcc (from Xcode). Homebrew openssl vs RVM openssl. Several versions of Ruby 1.9.3.

I get this error message when running 'rails new projectName'

`Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.`

I have edited the Gemfile and I am able to run the 'bundle install' however after that point, when I go to start the server 'rails s', I get the dreaded 'cannot load such file -- openssl'. This has shown up during a couple for the reinstalls as well but the latest mix of using Homebrew openssl and readline doesn't give these errors during install, just when I get to starting the server.

I will be happy to post any config files or setting that are needed to help diagnose the problem. I am using the stable release of RVM and on OS X 10.8.2. I am new to Mac (this is the second day) and have some basic unix experience, so kid glove explanations are welcome.

Comment: I can attest that using the --with-openssl-dir works for me. I would check two things: 1) are you using the RVM you think you are? Make sure using `rvm list` that you are indeed recompiling the ruby you're trying to use. 2) pay attention that the ssl dir is the one that contains the `lib` dir - so for MacPorts, it's "/opt/local", not "/opt/local/lib". Check this out: https://rvm.io/integration/macports/

Comment: Have you run `rvm requirements` and installed all of the listed libraries? (HomeBrew is an excellent choice for managing the required packages.)

Comment: I believe for most of these trials I was using the latest version of 1.9.3 but I will double check next run trough. I will also give macports a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041248/unable-to-create-a-first-rails-project

Answer (score 8):

Try to change the first line in your `Gemfile` from

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`   **to**   `source 'http://rubygems.org'`

I think this could solve your problem.

Comment: I have tired this but and it will take me a step further but anything else relating to openssl continues to fail.